# Extract all pagination links to pages with scrapy for url=https://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh/

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

can anyone please help me to Extract all pagination links to pages with scrapy  for `url=https://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh/`

AS i had alraedy tried with python 
but not fetching the details

my code is as follows=====================

```
allowed_domains = ['blablacar.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.blablacar.in/ride-sharing/new-delhi/chandigarh/']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('.trip-search-results li')
        for p in products:
            brand = p.css('.ProfileCard-info--name::text').extract_first().strip()
            price = p.css('.description .time::attr(content)').extract_first()
            item = ProductItem()
            item['brand'] = brand
            item['price'] = price
            yield item
        nextPageLinkSelector = response.css('.js-trip-search-pagination::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if nextPageLinkSelector:
            nextPageLink = nextPageLinkSelector
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(nextPageLink), )
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find a link to the next page and follow it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    products = response.css('.trip-search-results li')
    for p in products:
        brand = p.css('.ProfileCard-info--name::text').extract_first().strip()
        price = p.css('.description .time::attr(content)').extract_first()
        item = ProductItem()
        item['brand'] = brand
        item['price'] = price
        yield item

    # Here is the pagination following.
    for a_tag in response.css('.pagination .next:not(.disabled) a'):
        yield response.follow(a_tag, self.parse_route)
```

Comment: While executing the code getting error  as                                                              for trip in response.css('.trip-search-results li'):
                                                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @rijin.p make sure your indentation is consistent: it should consist of only spaces or only tabs. You seem to have mixed these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to follow the next page links:

```
nextPageLink = response.xpath("//*[@class='pagination']//*[@class='next' and not(contains(@class,'disabled'))]/a/@href").extract_first()
if nextPageLink:
    yield response.follow(nextPageLink,callback=self.parse)
```